# cgi - passing values in variables inside a loop

Tags: c, loops, cgi

So I'm trying to create a maze game that runs on localhost, and the code below almost works (it compiles). The program supposedly uses buttons as movement keys (UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT) and i use a parser to basically get the value returned by the button. However, since the whole thing is in a loop, every time I move (or pass the value of the data string) it keeps returning to the initial values of px and py (coordinates). My question is, how can I overwrite these values with each successive loop?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFLEN 22

void parse_button(char *data){
    char temp[100];
    int a=0;
    int count=0;
    while(data[count]!='='){
        count++;
    }
    count++;
    while(data[count]!=NULL){
        temp[a]=data[count];
        a++;
        count++;
    }
    strcpy(data,temp);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");
    printf("<html><body>");

    char *data;
    FILE *fp = fopen ("maze.txt", "r"); 
    char maze[20][BUFLEN];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int px = 1;
    int py = 0;



    data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    if(data){
        printf("%s", data);
    }
    parse_button(data);
    printf("<br>%s",data); //for checking if parser works
```

Here is the main algorithm of the maze:

```
    while(end!=1){
        printf("<table>");
        printf("<tr>");
            for (i=0; i<20; i++)    {
                fgets(maze[i], 22, fp);
            }

            for (i=0; i<20; i++){                           
                for (j=0; j<20; j++){       
                    printf("<td>");                 
                    printf("%c",maze[i][j]);                            
                    printf("</td>");                
                }
            printf("</tr>");        
            }
        printf("</table>");
        fclose(fp);
        if (!strcmp(data,"UP")){
            if (maze[px-1][py]=='X'){
                end++;
                printf("Nice! You've finished the maze! Congratulations!\n");
            }else if(maze[px-1][py]==' '){
                maze[px-1][py]='P';
                maze[px][py]=' ';               
                px--;   
            }else if(maze[px-1][py]=='*'){
                printf("Ouch! You've hit a wall! Try again!\n");
            }else
                break;
        }else if (!strcmp(data,"DOWN")){
            if (maze[px+1][py]=='X'){
                end++;  
                printf("Nice! You've finished the maze! Congratulations!\n");
            }else if(maze[px+1][py]==' '){
                maze[px+1][py]='P';
                maze[px][py]=' ';               
                px++;   
            }else if(maze[px+1][py]=='*'){
                printf("Ouch! You've hit a wall! Try again!\n");
            }else
                    break;
        }else if (!strcmp(data,"LEFT")){
            if (maze[px][py-1]=='X'){
                end++;
                printf("Nice! You've finished the maze! Congratulations!\n");
            }else if(maze[px][py-1]==' '){
                maze[px][py-1]='P';
                maze[px][py]=' ';               
                py--;   
            }else if(maze[px][py-1]=='*'){
                printf("Ouch! You've hit a wall! Try again!\n");
            }
        }else if (!strcmp(data,"RIGHT")){
            if (maze[px][py+1]=='X'){
                end++;
                printf("Nice! You've finished the maze! Congratulations!\n");
            }else if(maze[px][py+1]==' '){
                maze[px][py+1]='P';
                maze[px][py]=' ';               
                py++;   
            }else if(maze[px][py+1]=='*'){
                printf("Ouch! You've hit a wall! Try again!\n");
            }else
                break;      
        }else{
            printf("Invalid input! Enter w/s/a/d only!\n");
        }   
            printf("<form action=\"http://localhost/cgi-bin/maze.cgi\">");
    printf("<input type=submit name=\"button\" value='UP'>");
    printf("<input type=submit name=\"button\" value='DOWN'>");
    printf("<input type=submit name=\"button\" value='LEFT'>");
    printf("<input type=submit name=\"button\" value='RIGHT'>");
    printf("</form>");
    printf("</body></html>");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CGI will launch a new copy of the program each time a user presses a button. So you need to store the game state externally, i.e. in a file or database.

You also need a way to identify the user, so that you can retrieve the game state for that user. One way to do that is with a session cookie. How you create and retrieve session cookies depends on which web server you're using.

Comment: whats wrong with using a txt file and writing to it?